# How to give an initial value to NSManaged property in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I use Swift. I have a CoreData, and it has a string attribute called days. I want to assign a default value to this. I tried it in my CoreData model class but it gives an error saying *"NSManaged property cannot have an initial value"*.

This is what I tried.

```
@NSManaged var daysAvailable:String = "M"
```

Comment: Is it this you tried? https://i.imgur.com/VmVIWl0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it a static value, you can set it in the CoreData model editor in xcode.
No need to use 'awakeFromFetch' for that

Answer (score 9):

It's actually really easy. Just override the `awakeFromInsert` method for your `NSManagedObject` subclass.

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var age: NSNumber

    override func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()
        setPrimitiveValue(21, forKey: "age")
        setPrimitiveValue("Bob", forKey: "name")
    }
}
```

According to the `awakeFromInsert` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/awakeFromInsert):

> If you want to set attribute values in an implementation of this
>   method, you should typically use primitive accessor methods (either
>   setPrimitiveValue:forKey: or—better—the appropriate custom primitive
>   accessors). This ensures that the new values are treated as baseline
>   values rather than being recorded as undoable changes for the
>   properties in question.

Comment: useful for subclasses of subclasses of NSManagedObject when `@NSManaged override var variable: type = value` complains

Comment: You can also use `#keyPath` for safer key names: `setPrimitiveValue(UUID().uuidString, forKey: #keyPath(MyClass.identifier)).`

Comment: I had an "Overriding instance method must be as accessible as its enclosing type" error that was fixed by declaring the override as "override func awakeFromInsert" -- it did work after that! Thanks

Comment: Be very careful using awakeFromInsert() (and willSave() etc) if using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer. They will be called whenever the background sync makes local changes - i.e. inserting something from another device that has already done this setup. Checking that you are in a mainQueueConcurrencyType context before setting any values seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Override wake form insert to initialise core data object

```
 Override func awakeFromInsert()
 {
   super.awakeFromInsert()
   self.daysAvailable = "M"  
  }
```

check following link for more details:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html