# @NSManaged property cannot have an initial value

Tags: swift, core-data

i'm trying to store my api data in core data entity. I have some custom data types array also in them. So i made those attributes transformable. Like this,
[image]

Now when i created the `NSManagedObject` class of my entity, it's showing me error,

> @NSManaged property cannot have an initial value.

My `SingleChat+CoreDataProperties.swift` class is this,

```
extension SingleChat {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SingleChat> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SingleChat>(entityName: "SingleChat")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var roomSID: String?
    @NSManaged public var isGroup: Bool
    @NSManaged public var lastMessage: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastMsgTime: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastMsgTimeActual: String?
    @NSManaged public var profilePic: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastMsgRead: Bool
    @NSManaged public var unReadMsgsCount: Int16
    @NSManaged public var actualNameFor_1_2_1_chat: String?
    @NSManaged public var isNewGroup: Bool
    @NSManaged public var members = [TCHMember]()
    @NSManaged public var messages = [TCHMessage]()
    @NSManaged public var twChannelObj: TCHChannel?
    @NSManaged public var group_info: [String:JSON]?

}
```

I'm new to core data and does not know how i can get custom data types. How i can get resolve this issue, I want to store data in members, messages and group_info. These are arrays.

Comment: I am not certain, but I assume it's because optionals are default-initialized in swift, so stop using optionals (i.e. use `String` instead of `String?`) and also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229645/how-to-give-an-initial-value-to-nsmanaged-property-in-coredata) which might help too.

Comment: I'm getting this error on members and messages attributes . @trojanfoe

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: i want the array for messages and members. @vadian

Comment: Remove the *parentheses* `()` and keep the *square brackets* `[]`.

Comment: i have done that when i'm trying to store the data in this i'm getting this error, 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TCHMember encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28077a4c0' . @vadian

Comment: The error says that `TCHMember` must adopt `NSCoding`

Comment: Its i class of Twilio a third party SDK , how can i change that and use NSCoding in it. @vadian

Comment: `NSCoding` is a protocol to be able to serialize classes (to transform to `NSData`). I don't know the SDK. Can you subclass `TCHMember`? Or is it possible to write a wrapper to convert `TCHMember` to a Core Data entity and vice versa?

Comment: It is showing its subclass of TCHMember :  NSObject . and i have only used that in an array. @vadian